# Prototype function no longer working, coming up as undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have no idea what I did wrong. It worked before I uploaded to github.io so I'm suspicious I messed up some branches and am now stuck with an older file. I'm impossibly stuck and just need an outside perspective to figure it out.

It's a program to help order pizza (all in js/jquery), **it's no longer adding up the variables and returning an order total.** It says **var total is undefined**, and *I'm not completely sure whether it's my equations or variables.* I had it working fine before so I know it's possible with my code, I think I just made a mistake somewhere in the process of switching/adding branches that bungled it.

```
function order(sidesOrderedReduced, pizzaSauceReduced, beveragesOrderedReduced, dessertsOrderedReduced, pizzaToppingsReduced, zipcodeAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, total){
  this.sidesOrderedReduced = sidesOrderedReduced;
  this.beveragesOrderedReduced = beveragesOrderedReduced;
  this.dessertsOrderedReduced = dessertsOrderedReduced;
  this.pizzaSauceReduced = pizzaSauceReduced;
  this.pizzaToppingsReduced = pizzaToppingsReduced;
  this.zipcodeAddress = zipcodeAddress;
  this.cityAddress = cityAddress;
  this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
  this.total = total;
}

var sidesListed = [];
var sidesOrdered = [];
sidesOrderedReduced = sidesOrderedReduced || 0
var sidesOrderedReduced;
var beveragesListed= [];
var beveragesOrdered = [];
var beveragesOrderedReduced;
beveragesOrderedReduced = beveragesOrderedReduced || 0
var dessertsListed = [];
var dessertsOrdered = [];
var dessertsOrderedReduced;
dessertsOrderedReduced = dessertsOrderedReduced || 0

var pizzaSauceListed = [];
var pizzaSauce = [];
var pizzaSauceReduced = [];
pizzaSauceReduced = pizzaSauceReduced || 0
var pizzaToppingsListed = [];
var pizzaToppingsOrdered = [];
var pizzaToppingsReduced;
pizzaToppingsReduced = pizzaToppingsReduced || 0

var total;

var zipcodeAddress = $("input#zipcodeAddress").val();
var cityAddress = $("input#cityAddress").val();
var streetAddress = $("input#streetAddress").val();

var newOrder = new order(sidesOrderedReduced, beveragesOrderedReduced, dessertsOrderedReduced, pizzaSauceReduced, pizzaToppingsReduced, zipcodeAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, total);

order.prototype.total = function(){
  return this.beveragesOrderedReduced+this.sidesOrderedReduced+this.dessertsOrderedReduced+this.pizzaSauceReduced+this.pizzaToppingsReduced;
}

  $("input:checkbox[value=sides]:checked").each(function(){
    sidesListed.push($(this).attr("id"));
    sidesOrdered.push(5);
    sidesOrderedReduced =  sidesOrdered.reduceRight(function(a,b){return a+b;});
    return sidesOrderedReduced;
  });

  $("input:checkbox[value=pizzaSauce]:checked").each(function(){
    pizzaSauceListed.push($(this).attr("id"));
    pizzaSauce.push(10);
    pizzaSauceReduced =  pizzaSauce.reduceRight(function(a,b){return a+b;});
    return pizzaSauceReduced;
  });

  $("input:checkbox[value=pizzaToppings]:checked").each(function(){
    pizzaToppingsListed.push($(this).attr("id"));
    pizzaToppingsOrdered.push(1);
    pizzaToppingsReduced = pizzaToppingsOrdered.reduceRight(function(a,b){return a+b;});
    return pizzaToppingsReduced;
  });

  $("input:checkbox[value=beverages]:checked").each(function(){
    beveragesListed.push($(this).attr("id"));
    beveragesOrdered.push(3);
    beveragesOrderedReduced = beveragesOrdered.reduceRight(function(a,b){return a+b;});
    return beveragesOrderedReduced;
  });

  $("input:checkbox[value=desserts]:checked").each(function(){
    dessertsListed.push($(this).attr("id"));
    dessertsOrdered.push(5);
    dessertsOrderedReduced = dessertsOrdered.reduceRight(function(a,b){return a+b;});
    return dessertsOrderedReduced;
  });

  $("ul#orders").append(
       "<li><span class='orderInfo'>Order</span></li>");
     $(".orderInfo").last().click(function(){
       $("#show-info").show();
       $(".sides").text(sidesListed);
       $(".pizzaSauce").text(pizzaSauceListed);
       $(".pizzaToppings").text(pizzaToppingsListed);
       $(".beverages").text(beveragesListed);
       $(".desserts").text(dessertsListed);
       $(".zipcodeAddress").text(newOrder.zipcodeAddress);
       $(".streetAddress").text(newOrder.streetAddress);
       $(".cityAddress").text(newOrder.cityAddress);
       $(".total").text(newOrder.total);
     });
  //$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
  $("input#zipcodeAddress").val("");
  $("input#cityAddress").val("");
  $("input#streetAddress").val("");
});
```

});

Comment: Instead of pasting a large amount of code can you be more specific on what is the exact problem you are trying to solve? What have you tried so far? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's hardly any code.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean @hdifen about it being a lot of code but found it necessary for my problem. I rewrote it and made it easier to understand and bolded important text. I hope it makes it easier to understand what I'm asking for. I did read that when I posted my first question though!!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(".total").text(newOrder.total);
```

to

```
$('.total').text(newOrder.total());
```

`total` is a method. You just used it as a property.